# Как пробежаться по вложенным Map?

Tags: java, map

Есть map вида `Map<BigInteger, Map<BigInteger, Object>>`
В реальности иерархия гораздо сложнее. Как пробежаться по всем маппам и везде, где встречено нужное значение ключа - произвести замену значения?

Comment: Использовать Map.Entry#entrySet()

Comment: С Rx'ом знакомы? :D

Comment: И не стоит хранить столько элементов, чтобы их было аж `BigInteger`! Тем более пробегаться по ним...

Comment: Подумать об избавлении от вложенных мап? Иначе какой в них смысл, если вы вынуждены делать полный обход?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для сложной иерархии с непонятной степенью вложенности хорошо подойдет рекурсия, метод в итоге возвращает сколько всего замен было сделано:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static int findReplaceValueByKey(int key, String newValue, Map<Integer, Object> map) {
    int count = 0;

    for (Object o : map.values()) {
        if (o instanceof Map) {
            count = findReplaceValueByKey(key, newValue, (Map<Integer, Object>) o);
        }
    }

    if (map.replace(key, newValue) != null) {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Если нужно пробежаться по всем мапам самого глубокого уровня вложенности, то можно попробовать вложенные циклы `foreach` или функционалку:

```
// Map<BigInteger, Map<BigInteger, Map<BigInteger, Map<BigInteger, Object>>>> test;
// BigInteger compare_key;

// foreach
for ( Map<BigInteger, Map<BigInteger, Map<BigInteger, Object>>> v1 : test.values() )
    for ( Map<BigInteger, Map<BigInteger, Object>> v2 : v1.values() )
        for ( Map<BigInteger, Object> v3 : v2.values() )
            v3.computeIfPresent(compare_key, (key,value) -> null /* вместо "null" здесь должен быть расчёт нового значения */);

// то же, но в функционалке
test.values().forEach
(   v1 -> v1.values().forEach
    (   v2 -> v2.values().forEach
        (   v3 -> v3.computeIfPresent(compare_key, (key,value) -> null /* вместо "null" здесь должен быть расчёт нового значения */)
)   )   );
```

Если же для каждого уровня вложенности имеется свой ключ поиска, то можно попробовать цепочку вложенных вызовов `Map::computeIfPresent`:

```
// BigInteger compare_key_1, compare_key_2, compare_key_3;

test.computeIfPresent(compare_key_1, (key_1, value_1) ->
{   value_1.computeIfPresent(compare_key_2, (key_2, value_2) ->
    {   value_2.computeIfPresent(compare_key_3, (key_3, value_3) -> null /* вместо "null" здесь должен быть расчёт нового значения */);
        return value_2;
    });
    return value_1;
});
```

Если ключи есть не для всех уровней вложенности, то можно и комбинировать:

```
test.computeIfPresent(compare_key_1, (key_1, value_1) ->
{   value_1.values().forEach // нет ключа сравнения, проверяем все мапы данного уровня вложенности
    (   value_2 ->
        value_2.computeIfPresent(compare_key_3, (key_3, value_3) -> null /* вместо "null" здесь должен быть расчёт нового значения */)
    );
    return value_1;
});
```

Если я неправильно понял, что требуется, то просьба уточнить вопрос